# Understanding how audio is encoded on mysterious device to reprogram it

Tags: integrated-circuit, reverse-engineering, encryption, audio-codec

So I found a chanting lotus flower in the woods and I'm trying to figure out how to reprogram the audio on it... It has 4.5 hours of audio(!) stored on a 16MB flashrom, and is driven by a chip called JL16B-083A. At first I thought/hoped it was just an AC1082 clone playing straight MP3s, but when I looked closely at how it was wired I realized that wasn't the case and is something else (see pic below where I've labeled the traces).I've dumped the flash - it doens't seem like MP3s, but it doesn't really seem like anything recognizeable at all... All I know is that it's 4.5 hours long, implying it's running at about 8kpbs. I've tried my best to search various Chinese engines looking for anything on this part, but have come up empty...  Has anyone ever come across this chip before, or knows how the audio is encoded on the flash? Or how I might figure it out? Objective is to load it up with audio from the Conet project and possibly return it to the woods :)

[You can hear and see the thing in action here](https://youtu.be/jOyUGs_eoLE)

[Flash dump and more pictures here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uH5uuwAuahK7LY-CiW7Q5ArRyb6-SqVX?usp=share_link)

[image: Circuit board and identified pins]

Comment: Just because you found something in the woods does not automatically mean that you own it. Have you tried to return it to whoever might have lost it?

Answer (score 1):

That could be any of several dozen different microcontroller vendors.  You'd have to figure out which one, then obtain and learn their tool chain and you could (eventually) be able to program a new flash.

OR you can source something like an ardiuno or as  you say MP3 player, cut that circuit board out of the product, and put the new one in.